# Зачем здесь использовать call?

Tags: javascript

```
function showFullName() {
  alert( this.firstName + " " + this.lastName );
}

var user = {
  firstName: "Василий",
  lastName: "Петров"
};

showFullName.call(user) // "Василий Петров"
```

Когда вызвать эту функцию без `call`, то она выведет `undefined undefined`. Но почему? Если я передал ей аргумент `user`, и ее `this` становится `user`. Почему без `call` она не выводит `firstName` и `lastname` ?

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы передаете аргумент user, её this не становится user. У не появляется первый аргумент, равный user. А this зависит от контекста вызова (судя по всему в вашем случае это будет window). А вот используя call и bind, вы можете изменить её this